# Sorting object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have `object` which also has `object` as a value. I want to sort that `object` based on 'copy' key value. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y83f07w8/)

```
var x= {'one':{'copy':'b'},'two':{'copy':'v'},'three':{'copy':'a'}}

var getsort= []

for(i in x){
 var a= new Object();
    a[i]=x[i]

    getsort.push(a)
}

getsort.sort(function(a,b){
    //console.log(b)
    //console.log(a.copy)
    var textA = a.copy.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.copy.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
})
console.log(getsort)
```

Comment: Have a look at `getsort`. Is this really what you want to create? Do you not actually want `getsort.push(x[i])`?

Comment: After sorting I have to give the result in object format. like the way I am receiving it

Comment: expected output :  x= {'three':{'copy':'a'},'one':{'copy':'b'},'two':{'copy':'v'}}

Comment: Are you sure you want order in Object ? [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: I've created an answer before, but as I realized that you want the `Object` 'key to be ordered, I just delete my answer.

Comment: Yaa, I have seen your answer

Comment: so my question would be sorting key based on there value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
var x= {'one':{'copy':'b'},'two':{'copy':'v'},'three':{'copy':'a'}}

var getsort= []

for(i in x){
    if (i != undefined)
    {

    //console.log(i);
 var a= new Object();
    a[i]=x[i]
    //console.log(a[i]);
    getsort.push(a);
    }
}


function getValue(data)
{
    for(key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = data[key];
        return value;
    }
}
}

getsort.sort(function(a,b){
    console.log(getValue(b).copy)
    console.log(getValue(a).copy)
    var textA = getValue(a).copy.toUpperCase();
    var textB = getValue(b).copy.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
})
console.log(getsort);
```

Answer (score -1):

No, properties order in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript, you need to use an Array.

But to make an array you don't need to copy to another object in the loop

```
  var x= {'one':{'copy':'b'},'two':{'copy':'v'},'three':{'copy':'a'}}

    var getsort= [];

    for (i in x) {  
        getsort.push(x[i])
    }

    getsort.sort(function(a,b){

        var textA = a.copy.toUpperCase();
        var textB = b.copy.toUpperCase();

        return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;

    })
    console.log(getsort)
```

Comment: See what the OP wants. He want a `Object`. not `Array`.